# data populated in the dataframe during for loop but not there anymore after for loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas

so I have this data frame with about 5 columns. 2 of them are longitude and lattitude pairs in form of tuples. so I have another user defined function that calculates the distance between two given tuples of lon/lat.

```
data_all['gc_distance'] = ""

### let's start calculate the great circle distance
for idx, row in data_all.iterrows():
    row['gc_distance'] = gcd.dist(row['ping_location'], row['destination'])
    print(row)
```

so basically, i created an empty column named gc_distance, then i iterate through each row to calculate the distance. when i print each row, the data looks great;

sample print of a row:

```
created_at_des                                     2018-01-17 18:55:55.154000
location_missing                                                            0
ping_location                                (-121.9419444444, 37.4897222222)
destination                                            (-122.15057, 37.39465)
gc_distance                                                          23.85 km
Name: 393529, dtype: object
```

as you can see, the gc_distance DOES have value.

Here's the sample output from the print statement after the loop:

```
 location_missing              ping_location  \
                 0   (-152.859052, 51.218273)   
                 0    (120.585289, 31.298974)   
                 0    (120.585289, 31.298974)   
                 0    (120.585289, 31.298974)   
                 0  (121.4737021, 31.2303904)   

                    destination gc_distance  
    0  (-122.057005, 37.606922)              
    1  (-122.057005, 37.606922)              
    2  (-122.057005, 37.606922)              
    3  (-122.057005, 37.606922)              
    4  (-122.057005, 37.606922)
```

However, when I print it again outside of the for loop, gc_distance column has only blank vlaues! :(

Why is this??? There's no compile or run time error... And all other outputs look good, why is this calculated field not there, even though when I print it during the for loop it does have value? (but outside for loop it doesn't anymore)

Comment: print the dataframe `data_all` and show the result

Comment: @JulianRachman hi what do you mean? like print(data_all)? after i calculate the distance right?

Comment: yes. start with that

Comment: okay will add! thanks a bunch!

Comment: I recently had trouble with Excel reading and writing, and traced it ultimately to an incompatibility between my version of pandas and my version of *xlrd* (not the engine you are using, but the concept is the same).  In my case, I used the keyword argument *sheetname=1* only to find that the keyword had been changed to *sheet_name*, and the reader would not read.  So perhaps your writer is failing in a similar strange way.  In the end, I had to use the PyDev debugger to follow the execution into the engine code.

Comment: Wouldn't map() be a better choice than a loop?

def calculate_distance(x, y):
    return gcd.dist(x, y)

data_all['gc_distance'] = map(calculate_distance, data_all['ping_location'], data_all['destination'])

Comment: @MitchWheat i tried using map just now, the output became a map object at each row in column gc_distance... sorry im python noob, thanks for being patient.

Comment: @user5920660 thanks so much for the advice! so would upgrading both pandas and my xlsx writer sufficient to solve the issue? or did you find that was not useful as well?

Comment: @MitchWheat good thing is, at least when i use map, there's something in the excel output. however, it's outputing giberrish... as a "map object at XXXXXXX"

Comment: @JulianRachman you are right, when i print after the for loop, the gc_distance has nothing.... BUT WHY :(

Comment: print for me `data_all.iterrows()`

Comment: also, are you trying to find the greatest common denominator between rows of ping_location and destination?

Comment: @JulianRachman the iterrows will print: <generator object DataFrame.iterrows at 0x03795E40>

Comment: @JulianRachman no im not trying to find the GCD; and i've added some more print outs in my original question. hope that's what you've asked for?

Comment: try `print(data_all.iterrows)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163449/discussion-between-alwaysaskingquestions-and-julian-rachman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method out:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

def dist(i):
    diff = list(map(lambda a,b: a-b, df['a'][i], df['b'][i]))
    squared = [(k)**2 for k in diff]
    squared_diff = sum(squared)
    root = math.sqrt(squared_diff)
    return root



df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 5, 6, '', '', ''], [2, 6, -5, 8, '', '', '']], columns = ["x_a", "y_a", "x_b", "y_b", "a", "b", "dist"])
print(df)

#data_all['ping_location'] = list(zip(data_all.longitude_evnt, data_all.lattitude_evnt))

df['a'] = list(zip(df.x_a, df.y_a))     
df['b'] = list(zip(df.x_b, df.y_b)) 
print(df)

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    df['dist'][i] = dist(i)
    print(dist(i))

print(df)
```

This is my terminal output:

```
   x_a  y_a  x_b  y_b a b dist
0    0    0    5    6         
1    2    6   -5    8         
   x_a  y_a  x_b  y_b       a        b dist
0    0    0    5    6  (0, 0)   (5, 6)     
1    2    6   -5    8  (2, 6)  (-5, 8)     
test.py:24: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['dist'][i] = dist(i)
7.810249675906654
7.280109889280518
   x_a  y_a  x_b  y_b       a        b     dist
0    0    0    5    6  (0, 0)   (5, 6)  7.81025
1    2    6   -5    8  (2, 6)  (-5, 8)  7.28011
```